# How can I plot a 3D graphic using rcaller?

Tags: java, r, rcaller

I´m trying to plot a 3D graphic but unfortunately doesn´t worked so far.

I´m using the follow code

```
        RCaller caller = new RCaller();
        Globals.detect_current_rscript();
        caller.setRscriptExecutable(Globals.Rscript_current);
        caller.setGraphicsTheme(new DefaultTheme());

        RCode code = new RCode();
        code.clear();

        double[] y = new double[]{1, 4, 3, 5, 6, 10};
        double[] x = new double[]{3, 6, 5, 9, 8, 13};
        double[] z = new double[]{2, 3, 1, 7, 8, 18};

        code.addDoubleArray("x", x);
        code.addDoubleArray("y", y);
        code.addDoubleArray("z", z);

        code.addRCode("plot3d(x,y,z)");
        code.R_require("rgl");

        caller.setRCode(code);
        File file = code.startPlot();
        caller.runOnly();
        ImageIcon i=code.getPlot(file);
        code.showPlot(file);
```

When I run the aplication I can see the graphic for a few seconds and then it just disappears.

Can rCaller plot 3D graphic or I´m doing something wrong???

Thanks